# Alert em apenas determinado navegador

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

É possível somente com JavaScript e HTML fazer aparecer um `alert` somente e só quando o usuário estiver navegando pelo Internet Explorer?

Por exemplo quando for navegar pelo Google Chrome o `alert` não aparece, mas sim quando for navegar pelo Internet Explorer

Comment: O Explorer não é um _browser_. Editei sua pergunta e troquei "Explorer" por "Internet Explorer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível obtendo as propriedades do navegador:

```
function identificarBrowse() {
    var nav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (nav.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
        alert("IE");
    }
}
```

### Nota

A forma de identificar IE11 foi alterada, usei a solução do Joachim:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907562/3444041

---

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/bxekLzaz/3/